# How do you create credentials for third parties (customers) for GCP Artifact Registry?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, containers, google-artifact-registry

I am publishing software I made to a GCP container registry for customers to use. I would like customers to have individually-assigned, long-lived, preferably revocable credentials that give them access to pull images of this proprietary software. But it seems like the way GCP Artifact Repository works is that containers are either totally public, or you have to use the `gcloud` CLI, or Application Default Credentials to create short-lived access tokens, which is probably not acceptable. Am I missing something?

Comment: You need a Google credential to access Google resources; and to authorize the credential to access the ressource. It's fairly acceptable... However, I can understand that the whole world (and your customer) does  not use Google. In that case, you must create an additional layer to authenticate your user (without Google Account) and create a short lived credential for them to allow them to pull your image. For instance, it's the same with dockerhub (you need a dockerhub credential + authorization to pull the images of a private repo)